# Windows 7 doesn't list wireless networks but connections to manually setup wireless profiles works

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

On a Dell Latitude E4310 laptop with *Intel(R) Centrino(R) Ultimate-N 6300 AGN* network adapter, suddenly windows 7 stopped showing available network list. However wifi itself works as it connects to default network i have a profile set up.

I have since searched for latest drivers and upgraded the drivers, but still doesn't work as expected.

Does someone has any suggestions? Should it be hardware fault?

I really know that I unplugged my ethernet cable and that the wifi switch is on prior to asking a question.

Answer (score 0):

Manually set up a wireless network(one which does not broadcast SSID) under Control Panel\Network and Internet\Manage Wireless Network(for some reason this particular path doesn't work :/ but go to Control Panel then search for "Manage Wireless Networks" in the search bar at the top).  You can optionally check Connect Automatically, but you **must** check the last check box that says "Connect even if the network is not broadcasting *SSID"

Then go to `Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network and Sharing Center` and towards the bottom there is a "Connect to a network" link that will popup a small popup from the systray where your wireless network will be listed, click it then click "Connect" button.  If you don't click the checkbox I mentioned above, it won't even be listed :/  Really frustrated me.